# Nodejs not able to concurrently access a file from two apps

Tags: file, concurrency, nodes, tail

I have two nodejs apps. One is writing logs to a file using rotating-file-stream. 
The second app needs to consume these logs and process by reading the log file as it is changing. Basically I am trying to setup a crude disk based queue. The issue I am seeing is that the consumer app is not able to see the logs until the stream from producer app is closed.

On this consumer app I tried fs.watch, chokidar and tail (I am not even getting change event). However, when I tried running 'tail -f' on the terminal that is able to pick up changes right away.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found it seems like it is a platform related issue, which in my case is macOS. Using fs.watchFile instead of fs.watch fixed the issue. Thankfully the libraries I am using (chokidar and tail) provides api flags to do just that.